# Initialize ModelChoiceField in Form

Tags: python, django, forms, initialization

My `form.py`

```
class BannerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=32)
    affiliation = forms.ModelChoiceField(Affiliation.objects.all(), disabled = True, initial='Red')
```

My `model.py`

```
class Affiliation (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Banner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    affiliation = models.ForeignKey(Affiliation)
```

My `populate` script (to run at begin to populate the database)

```
def populate():
    red = add_affiliation('Red')
    black = add_affiliation('Black')
```

When I fill a form to create a Banner it doesn't work, it doesn't see Red (o red) like a valid choice:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>affiliation<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

I changed my `form.py`:

```
class BannerForm(forms.ModelForm):
        name = forms.CharField(max_length=32)
affiliation = forms.ModelChoiceField(Affiliation.objects.all(), disabled = True, initial=Affiliation.objects.get(id=1))
```

And give the same error. I changed again:

```
class BannerForm(forms.ModelForm):
        name = forms.CharField(max_length=32)
        affiliation = forms.ModelChoiceField(Affiliation.objects.all(), widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=Affiliation.objects.get(id=1))
```

It work, but only if I change code when the database already exist because if not my first migration give an error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: core_affiliation
```

How can I resolve? I would prefer to do not use HiddenInput and to do not hardcode the id, if possible.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe do you need more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved. 
A disabled field can't be used to pass data so I add a field to display the data and another (hidden) to actually pass data.

```
form.py

class BannerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=32)
    Affiliazione = forms.CharField(disabled = True, required=False)
    affiliation = forms.ModelChoiceField(Affiliation.objects.all(),
    widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

I initialize them by the `views`:

```
def add_banner(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #some code
    else:
        options = Options.objects.get(id=1)
        form = BannerForm(request.POST or None, initial={
            'Affiliazione': options.new_affiliation,
            'affiliation': options.new_affiliation})
    return render(request, 'core/add_banner.html', {'form': form})
```

I create the Options model to contain the initial variable and if the variable are on views.py the migration work well...